# Write data to multiple non-consecutive cells in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I've been looking on here, and youtube, and google for ages, and I still can't seem to get my script to work. here is a link to a test sheet :

[test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O_gOKBhsOMrZTjg5FfpJhA4iwsCcxyz6prNu29zSUoU/edit?usp=sharing)

Simply put, I have lots of data in non adjacent cells that needs to be changed, and want to write a script to do it (if possible, I have lots of sheets to do). So, my thinking was to do something like this :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRangeList(['A1','B2','C3','D4','E5']).setValues([10,9,8,7,6]);

}
```

Code obviously doesn't work, not sure why though. could anybody enlighten me?

Thanks,

EDIT : The only way I can manage to do it is cell by cell, like this :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1').setValue(10);
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B2').setValue(9);
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('C3').setValue(8);
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('D4').setValue(7);
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('E5').setValue(6);
}
```

Comment: There are several reasons.  First of all getRangeList does not return a range and both setValue() and setValues() are range methods.

Comment: In addtion setValues() takes a two dimensional array and writes it into a rectangular range.  The size of the range and size of the array have to be an exact match.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dA=[10,9,8,7,6];
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRangeList(['A1','B2','C3','D4','E5']).getRanges().forEach(function(rg,i){
    rg.setValue(dA[i]);
  });
}
```

A method of rangeList is [getRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#getRanges()) and it returns an array of ranges which plays very nicely into using javascripts array methods like [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Within the forEach you can set each value and in this case I put the values into an array so that I could select them with the index which is the forEach's second parameter.

And the end result looks like this:

[image]

In the future I recommend that you pay close attention to the types of objects that methods return.  Also if you lose your content assist display it's a sign that you are doing something and you should go back to a point where it begins again and somewhere between there and where you are right now you have made an error in your coding.

This is what content assist looks like:

[image]